# Merging an undetermined number of rows in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
tid ||  instr_count || fnname
=============================
22  ||      892806  || main
22  ||          18  || randlc
22  ||         120  || makea
```

I'd like to merge the values of `instr_count` together based on whether or not `fnname` appears in a given list. For example, if my list is `['main', 'makea']`, the final table should look like this:

```
tid ||  instr_count || fnname
=============================
22  ||      892806  || main
22  ||         138  || makea
```

I don't know ahead of time how many entries will be between 2 values in the given list - so it may be more akin to this:

```
tid ||  instr_count || fnname
=============================
22  ||      892806  || main
22  ||          18  || randlc
22  ||           7  || randlc
22  ||          35  || randlc
22  ||          20  || randlc
22  ||         120  || makea
```

Which should be compressed down to:

```
tid ||  instr_count || fnname
=============================
22  ||      892806  || main
22  ||         200  || makea
```

I've loaded these values into a `Dataframe` using pandas 0.17.1 and python 2.7.6. Here's what I have so far:

```
def compressDataframes(df):

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    instr_count = 0
    i = 0
    for row in df.itertuples():
        instr_count += row[2]
        if any(f in row[3] for f in FUNCS): #FUNCS is my "given list"
            new_df.loc[i] = [row[1], instr_count, row[3]]
            i += 1
            instr_count = 0

    return new_df
```

This works, but I suspect there must be a way to do it faster (I'm working with some very large (> 10 GB) datasets). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for creating new column `grouped`, which first contains `NaN` where are not data and then by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) is filled valid observation to fill gap (backfill). Last with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) aggregate [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) of column `instr_count`:

```
li = ['main','makea']

df['grouped'] = df.loc[df['fnname'].isin(li), 'fnname']

df['grouped'] = df['grouped'].fillna(method='bfill')

print df
   tid  instr_count  fnname grouped
0   22       892806    main    main
1   22           18  randlc   makea
2   22          120   makea   makea

print df.groupby(['tid','grouped'])['instr_count'].sum().reset_index()
   tid grouped  instr_count
0   22    main       892806
1   22   makea          138
```

Or with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
print df.groupby('grouped').agg({'tid':'first', 'instr_count': sum}).reset_index()

  grouped  tid  instr_count
0    main   22       892806
1   makea   22          138
```

Second sample:

```
li = ['main','makea']
df['grouped'] = df.loc[df['fnname'].isin(li), 'fnname']
df['grouped'] = df['grouped'].fillna(method='bfill')

print df
   tid  instr_count  fnname grouped
0   22       892806    main    main
1   22           18  randlc   makea
2   22            7  randlc   makea
3   22           35  randlc   makea
4   22           20  randlc   makea
5   22          120   makea   makea

print df.groupby(['tid','grouped'])['instr_count'].sum().reset_index()
  grouped  tid  instr_count
0    main   22       892806
1   makea   22          200

print df.groupby('grouped').agg({'tid':'first', 'instr_count': sum}).reset_index()
   tid grouped  instr_count
0   22    main       892806
1   22   makea          200
```

Comment: Just realized - I don't think this will work properly if I have something like `main, randlc, randlc, makea, makea`. The first `makea` will get grouped into the second, won't it?

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the row number into the grouped column? That would make for a unique identifier that could then be backfilled.

Comment: ^ Did exactly that by adding an index row and using that as the column instead of `'fnname'`. Thank you again for this answer!